# Suggest a word for the dark side of "curiosity"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a suitable term for "negative curiosity" that represents the concept of wandering and prying in the workplace. Is there a common word?
For example, when an employee is prying into a co-worker, he or she wants to know things he or she is not allowed to know, or when he or she asks questions about his or her co-worker's personal life.

Comment: Welcome! Please take a moment to read about [the topics covered here](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). In particular, word or phrase requests must include a sample sentence showing how the word would be used. You'll also get better results if you can explain more about the idea you're going for, and why "prying" doesn't satisfy it. Perhaps "morbid curiosity" or "snooping" is what you're going for.

Comment: Answers should not be posted in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You might describe such an employee as [nosy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nosy#Adjective). This suggests being inquisitive about other people, to the extent that those other people find it intrusive.

Comment: The answer was good. Thank you

Comment: Downvoter, please could you suggest a way I could improve my answer?